# How can I install the Inuktitut language on ubuntu? If no language package for this language exist, how can I create one?

Tags: ubuntu, input-languages

Dear honorable reader:

*Summarize the problem:*

How can I install the Inuktitut language on ubuntu? If no language package for this language exist, how should I create one?

*Provide details and any research*

I'm a native Inuit and I want to be able to type in Inuktitut and I want my system to be in Inuktitut. I googled "How can I install the Inuktitut language on ubuntu?", but none of them are relevant, so I'm out of means now.

Thank you for answering, honorable reader.

Comment: Please see if this resource helps you (geared more toward Windows) https://www.gov.nu.ca/culture-and-heritage/information/computer-tools  . You may already be familiar with this resource.